# UWP TextBox uneditable Border Color that only appears on Mouse Hover

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I want to create a create user section. To make it look more appealing I wanted the text boxes to only have a border under them, and that border to be their system accent color. That works all fine until the user hovers their mouse over the border. At this point the border turns solid black. I have found the property that causes this; however, cannot work with it.

The property that is setting to solid black is `FocusVisualSecondaryBrush`. However under the visual studio properties window, TextBox doesn't have that property.

Please help me.

Comment: [Does Visual Studio Rot the Mind?](http://www.charlespetzold.com/etc/DoesVisualStudioRotTheMind.html). There isn't a GUI tool for everything. It's not the end of the world. Besides, consider updating your question title to make a bit more sense. It doesn't really match the question you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

`TextBox.BorderBrush` is used only for the `Normal` visual state. When the pointer is over the control, or when it is focused, the border brush is set to something else. If you right click the textbox in the designer `-> Edit Template -> Edit a Copy` you'll see the default style for the textbox control.

The easiest way to achieve what you want is to add the following resources to the element with the closest scope to the textboxes you want to affect:

```xml
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextControlBorderBrushPointerOver"
                 Color="{ThemeResource SystemAccentColor}"/>
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
            Value="{StaticResource SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush}"/>
</Style>
```

If you add these resources to your `Page.Resources`, then it will affect all textboxes on that page.